# Jenkins build successful despite failed JBehave steps

Tags: jenkins, junit, bdd, jbehave

For GUI testautomation we have set up a Maven project using JBehave (v4.0.4) as a BDD framework. The stories are executed with a `JUnitReportingRunner` and run continously in a Jenkins (v1.630) master slave environment.

I recently noticed that in some cases, the Jenkins build is marked as successful despite some failed steps. The XUnit test report correctly indicates that there is a failed test while the Jenkins build does not. We haven't configured any thresholds concerning the build status. Therefore one failed test should cause the build to fail (and it does most of the time).

This problem is very annoying since we heavily rely on the Jenkins mail notifications. Any pointers on how to solve it are very much appreciated.

Comment: Triple check these thresholds are set to 0, i once made the mistake to set it to 1 ending up allowing 1 error. Without more information on the exact configuration its not easy to help.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. The thresholds haven't been set at all; now I set them explicitly to 0. Which configuration details would you consider as useful? I'm still baffled by this nondeterministic behavior and don't know where to start.

Comment: Oh this explains it. When you dont set them the test results will not change the job result at all. I.e. useful when you just want the informative value from some tests while having i.e. email triggers only sent out on build errors.